# Crystal Report 13_0_9 error A Date-Time is Required Here

Tags: sql, vb.net, date, datetime, crystal-reports

I need to filter my Report with a specific DATE 
anyone can help me to debug this?

> the error is : "A date-time is required here"

Here is code

```
Dim ds As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dp_Exp.Text)
    Dim de As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dp_Exp.Text).AddDays(1)
    frm_ReportMember.CrystalReportViewer1.Enabled = True
    frm_ReportMember.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource =        "C:\Users\Paolo\Desktop\UpdatedComputerized\ComputerizedMembership\WindowsApplication1\ReportMember.rpt"
frm_ReportMember.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{RegularMember.PromoCode} = '" _
& cmb_Promo.SelectedItem.ToString & "'"                                                                    & " AND {RegularMember.DateExpiry} >= #" & dp_Exp.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") _
& "# AND {RegularMember.DateExpiry} < #" & dp_Exp.Value.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"
frm_ReportMember.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
frm_ReportMember.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
frm_ReportMember.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `{RegularMember.DateExpiry}` is supposedly a Datetime field and you are passing a `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` value to it. That could be causing it.

try formatting your {RegularMember.DateExpiry} this way and then pass it:

```
string.format("DateTime({0:yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss})", {RegularMember.DateExpiry});
```